# Gym at Dubai International Hotel in T3

Tags: transit, dxb

I have a 3 hour stopover in Dubai arriving and departing T3.

I've been told I can make use of the abovementioned hotel's fitness centre is this true?

I've emailed them twice regarding this ( using their website "contact us" ) and am yet to receive a reply.

Short of actually calling them  I was just wondering if anyone could enlighten me regarding this as it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are describing the [G-Force Health Club](https://www.emirates.com/au/english/plan_book/dubai_international_airport/facilities.aspx), in [concourses C and B](https://www.dubaiintlhotels.com/hotel/facilities) of Terminal 3.

It appears to cost about [$13/hour](http://www.travelandleisure.com/travel-guide/dubai-international-airport-dxb/things-to-do/g-force-health-club), though there are also spa packages available that include the gym.

Answer (score -1):

Why not call them? +971 4 224 4000

If you've been told you can make use of the fitness centre, then it sounds like you can...

It's a paid-for service, but well worth it to refresh while on a stopover.

Comment: That was my next step Dave......just wasn't  sure is all.....thanks for  your input,,,,,appreciate the feedback